# get data from wp-query, outside the loop & without url change

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I am working on an advanced search on wordpress based on custom taxonomies.
I've been stuck for 72h so I was hoping to have some help or thought...

**Step 1** --- in the js file the query strings are created like that:

```
if (jQuery('#s').val() == ''){
URL = "/?genre=" + genre + '...other Stuff' #content';
}else{
URL = "/?s="+searchQueryString+"&genre=" + genre +'...other stuff' #content';
}
```

It nicelly load my custom loop in my #content div without changing the browser url or reloading the header, which is pretty good...so far. :-)

**Step 2** --- then I wrote 2 functions in my function.php , one to load the loop with the GET[] elements on main page, using `new WP_Query` 
and one that does the same thing for search queries but only filter with:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Which is compiling my GET[] filters with the GET[s] in the content.php,
Still all good....

**Step 3** --- (problem^^)---

I want to add a css class to desactivate the radio buttons located in my header.php, depending on the results in the loop.

**Try-1** I thought I could create a php array to compile the terms found while the loop is happening, and then compare it with my buttons value.like that:

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'slugs');
$results = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(),'category',$args);  
foreach ($results as $result){
    array_push($stack, $result);

}
```

But there is no way to retrieve the data from that array in the header afterwhile, or to create it from the header using things like `global $post;`since my url doesn't change.
it just shows the homepage query.

**Try-2** I also thought I could encode it to json and then put some action in my js file. but so far it just return json unexpected character, and I got the feeling that even if I crack it, its not going to be the right way since its going to make the js file heavier.

May be I'm just missing something about the Global wp_query and I don't need to charge my script?

Excuse my english and the long question,

thanks a lot in advance if you have an idea,

DACO

Comment: Exactly what is the question? In a single sentence?

Comment: I guess that would be: "How can I get query-results from the main loop ,in the header, without refreshing the url?"...Hope its kind of clear^^, I am trying mwweb solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) which lets you pass data to a script that is already enqueued.

It works roughly like this:

```
<?php    
// assuming your script is already registered
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse_81817' );

// Do the array building of terms you plan on doing
$wpse_81817_phpdata = array( 'myKey' => 'a value' );

// Pass that to the JS
wp_localize_script( 'wpse_81817', 'wpse_81817_jsdata', $wpse_81817_phpdata );
```

Then, in your `wpse_81817` script, you can get at the data like so:

```
print wpse_81817_jsdata.myKey;
```

That should return:

```
'a value'
```

Comment: Thanks mrwweb ! it sounds like its going to make the job!